# nvprof events "fb_subp0_read_sectors" and "fb_subp1_read_sectors" do not report correct results

Tags: cuda, nvidia, profiler

I tried to count the number of DRAM (global memory) accesses for simple vector add kernel.

```
__global__ void AddVectors(const float* A, const float* B, float* C, int N)
{
    int blockStartIndex  = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * N;
    int threadStartIndex = blockStartIndex + threadIdx.x;
    int threadEndIndex   = threadStartIndex + ( N * blockDim.x );
    int i;

    for( i=threadStartIndex; i<threadEndIndex; i+=blockDim.x ){
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}
```

Grid Size = 180
Block size = 128

size of array = 180 * 128 * N floats where N is input parameter (elements per thread)

when N = 1, size of array = 180 * 128 * 1 floats = 90KB

All arrays A, B and C should be read from DRAM.

Therefore theoretically,

DRAM writes (C) = 2880 (32 byte accesses)
DRAM reads (A,B) = 2880 + 2880 = 5760 (32 byte accesses)

But when I used nvprof

DRAM writes = fb_subp0_write_sectors + fb_subp1_write_sectors = 1440 + 1440 = 2880 (32 byte accesses)
DRAM reads = fb_subp0_read_sectors + fb_subp1_read_sectors = 23 + 7 = 30 (32 byte accesses)

Now this is the problem. Theoretically there should be 5760 DRAM reads, but nvprof only reports 30, for me this looks impossible. Further more, if you double the size of the vector (N = 2), still the reported DRAM accesses remains at 30.

It would be great, if someone can shed some light.

I have disabled the L1 cache by using compiler option "`-Xptxas -dlcm=cg`"

Thanks,
Waruna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have done `cudaMemcpy` before the kernel launch to copy the source buffers from host to device, that gets the source buffers in L2 cache and hence the kernel doesn't see any misses from L2 for reads and you get less number of (`fb_subp0_read_sectors + fb_subp1_read_sectors`).

If you comment out `cudaMemcpy` before the kernel launch, you will see that the event values of `fb_subp0_read_sectors` and `fb_subp1_read_sectors` include the values you are expecting.

Comment: I also copy Array C from host to device. Therefore, there should  not be any L2 write misses. But when I check with the profiler, it shows 2880 write misses. Could you please explain this behavior?